# Game of craps looping more than once after quitting the game

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program to play a game of craps where the user enters a bet amount, then they roll 2 six sided dice. If the sum of the dice s 2,3 or 12 they lose. 7 or 11 they win. if any other number is rolled the player keeps rolling until they get the point number to win or 7 to lose. However for some reason if I select n to not play again it still loops the game a second time before quitting. I am not sure why
any help would be appreciated.

```cs
static void processCraps()
{
    string gameStatus = null;
    double betAmount =0;
    double netWinning = 0;
    int point;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount to bet");
            betAmount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invaid input try again");
        }

        var diceRoll = RollDice();
        if (diceRoll == 2 || diceRoll == 3 || diceRoll == 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You lost {betAmount}");
            netWinning = netWinning - betAmount;
        }
        else if (diceRoll == 7 || diceRoll == 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You won {betAmount}");
            netWinning = netWinning + betAmount;
        }
        else if (diceRoll != 2 || diceRoll != 3 || diceRoll != 12 || diceRoll != 7 || diceRoll != 11)
        {
            point = diceRoll;
            Console.WriteLine($"Point is {point}");
            for (int rollCount = 0; rollCount >= point; rollCount++)
            {
                var roll = RollDice();
                if (roll == 7)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You lost {betAmount}");
                    netWinning = netWinning - betAmount;
                }
                else if (roll == point)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You won {betAmount}");
                    netWinning = netWinning + betAmount;
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again (y/n)");
            gameStatus = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("answer must be a letter");
        }
    } while (gameStatus != "n") ;
    Console.WriteLine($"Your net winning is {netWinning}");
}
```

Comment: 1) Clean up your code. Line up code blocks. Get rid of extraneous blank lines. The easier your code is to read, the easier it is to identify problems. If you're using Visual Studio, you can start with CTRL+E,D 2) Use the debugger. It's an indispensable tool for troubleshooting. It will allow you to step through your code line by line and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read input twice.

You may want to split the logic into two loops. 1. Read bet amount. 2. Play game.

```
do 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount to bet, or 'q' to quit:");
    var betStr = Console.ReadLine();
    if( betStr == "q") return;
    double.TryParse(betStr, out betAmount);
} while (betAmount != 0);
```

```
do
{
    //Play
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again (n = quit)?");
    gameStatus = Console.ReadLine();
} while (gameStatus != "n");
```